# For electron app in macOS, when is app.quit() invoked?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new to electron, and I try to understand the starting code. I am confused about one block of code.

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

What the code does is it terminates the whole program if all windows are closed, and macOS is an exception.

The problem is, there is no other handler for a macOS to invoke `app.quit()`. So I wonder in macOS, if we don't call `app.quit()` manually, will it be invoked automatically when we press `command + q`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Electron docs are pretty good: [Event: 'window-all-closed'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-window-all-closed)

> **Event: 'window-all-closed'**
>
> *Emitted when all windows have been closed.*
>
> If you do not subscribe to this event and all windows are closed, the
>   default behavior is to quit the app; however, if you subscribe, you
>   control whether the app quits or not. If the user pressed Cmd + Q, or
>   the developer called app.quit(), Electron will first try to close all
>   the windows and then emit the will-quit event, and in this case the
>   window-all-closed event would not be emitted.

As for the default OSX behavior

> On Windows systems, a window generally equals an application. This
>   means that when you close a window, you close the application as well
>   (as long as it’s the last window of that application that’s open). On
>   a Mac, a window is treated more like a document than the app itself.
>   When you close a window, you close the specific document you were
>   looking at, but the application itself keeps running.
>   – https://www.howtogeek.com/279086/why-do-mac-apps-stay-open-when-i-hit-the-red-x-button/